# Shipping Charges not Showing in One-Page Checkout Progress Block

Tags: magento-enterprise, onepage-checkout

Delivery Surcharges and/or Shipping Charges (when applicable) are not showing in our One-Page Checkout Progress Block under 'Totals'. More specifically here: 'Your Checkout Progress > Payment Method > Totals' but these shipping charges do show up in the 'Shopping Cart' and on the 'Order Review' step of checkout. Please see image below:

[image]

Using Template Path Hints the block in question is shown here: frontend/base/default/template/{your package}/couponopc/checkout/onepage/progress/totals.phtml - But after looking in that file I only see a comment saying 'Dynamically loaded' as you see below. So is this essentially an issue with checkout.xml? I don't see one here: app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/layout/checkout.xml but I do see one here: app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml - I have included the applicable code from that file further down. I am not sure how to proceed from here.

from totals.phtml

```
<dt class="complete">
    <?php echo $this->__('Totals') ?>
</dt>
<dd class="complete">
    <table id="checkout-onepage-progress-totals">
        <tbody id="checkout-onepage-progress-totals-tbody">
            <!-- Dynamically loaded -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</dd>
```

from checkout.xml

```
<reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChildren"></action>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.progress.wrapper" translate="label">
                <label>Checkout Progress Wrapper</label>
                <action method="setElementId"><value>checkout-progress-wrapper</value></action>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="checkout.progress" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="billing.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml"></block>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shipping.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml"></block>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shippingmethod.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml"></block>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="payment.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/payment.phtml"></block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
```